# Why Azure WebJobs blade is showing no webjobs

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-appservice

Basically i am curious why the WebJobs blade for my App Service shows 0 webjobs ("You haven't added any WebJobs. Click ADD to get started"). And of course, when i click Add, i get "WebJob cannot be added from portal if development from source control is configured.").

I am following this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to). As with almost any technical guide, things get outdated very quickly and frequently. So i'm trying to following this the best i can.

Note that my snippet (taken from the link) essentially looks like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        config = new JobHostConfiguration();
        var host = new JobHost(config);
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }
}
```

To paraphrase: I am not see my WebJob under my App Service.

**Question:**
Based on this link/guide, the WebJob simply exists in the solution. There is the Program.cs (the entry point of the app service/host), and then there is the WebJob itself ( Functions.cs, which has a basic implementation with a QueueTrigger("queue") ). Why is the WebJob not showing up under the WebJobs blade under the App Service?

Answer (score 0):

If you have source control configured with your application, the webjobs should be deployed as part of the source control integration.

Form App Service perspective a webjob is just part of the content of the app.

If you deploy a webjob through the portal and then had a commit to your source control, then **the webjob would be removed since it wasn't part of the payload being published by source control**.

The right way to do this is to make sure webjobs are part of your solution.

As a workaround, you can **deploy webjobs through FTP/FTPS** but keep in mind they will be removed the moment source control does the next deployment.

Or you could **upload the webjobs directly via the Kudu Console**.

Open the Kudu Console by selecting "Advanced Tool" --> "Go" in Your App Service on the Azure Portal then Go to the directory for your webjobs: `d:\home\site\wwwroot\app_data\jobs\continuous\{job name}` drag and drop the .zip file you prepared to upload your webjob

Comment: How would you say 
```If you deploy a webjob through the portal and then had a commit to your source control, then the webjob would be removed since it wasn't part of the payload being published by source control```
Why is it happening like this? Is there any document for this?